Video play in browser hangs after wake up from suspend mode
Playing video in browser works fine in Ubuntu 24, but after suspend-mode and after waking up, video play in browser does not work anymore, at all. Video hangs and keeps loading, while there is not a network or connectivity issue.  This is in Firefox, but also in Chrome. Restarting the browser does not not fix this problem. Restarting the OS does fix the problem, but this not a good solution. The system has a NVIDIA videocard, which is in use by the system. Suggestions? Solutions?
